# var hFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/ex1/cen.csv") Input path does not exist error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to access hadoop file in spark but I am getting this error

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/ex1/cen.csv
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
```

I am able to display the file in hadoop

```
hadoop dfs -cat ex1/cen.csv
```

Comment: Have you tried .textFile("file:///path to the file/")?

Comment: yes...not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try

```
hadoop dfs -cat ex1/cen.csv
```

the path to read the file in HDFS is

```
/user/.../ex1/cen.csv
```

But if you try

```
hadoop dfs -cat /ex1/cen.csv
```

Directory /ex1 has to be placed in the root directory /
What you are trying to do with

```
 hdfs://localhost:9000/ex1/cen.csv
```

is to read from the root directory, and I think, your file isn't there because

```
/ex1/cen.csv

ex1/cen.csv
```

are different paths.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem
I tried the command 
hdfs dfs -ls /
and used the directory path of folders shown in this iisting and it worked fine.I guess the issue was with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the hive-site.xml into `conf` folder of spark will resolve the issue !!